# SQL Server : union in a while loop

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, union

I step with a while statement though a table to get some counts

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;

WHILE @cnt < 10
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS aantal,
        lt_Gebouw.gebouw AS gebouw,
        CAST( GETDATE() AS Date ) AS 'per datum'
    FROM 
        [VGNSalto].[dbo].[tb_Locks] 
    JOIN
        lt_Gebouw ON lt_Gebouw.gebouw = LEFT(tb_Locks.name, 3)
    WHERE
        lt_gebouw.nummer = @cnt
    GROUP BY
        lt_Gebouw.gebouw
  
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

As a result I get 10 separate tables with 1 row each; what I want is 1 table with 10 rows.

Like a 'union' statement to join multiple select statements. I tried union on different places but no success.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why are you looping at all?

Comment: SQL is a set based language, it excels at set based solutions. As a result it performs awfully at iterative tasks, as they are the complete opposite of that methodology. There are *very* few times you should be looping in SQL; why are you looping here? Most likely you shouldn't be using one.

Comment: Don't use loops in SQL. This is the slowest and most complicated way possible to do anything. What are you trying to do? Post the table schema, example data and desired output. Whatever you want, you don't need loops to get it

Comment: Although I suspect what you want is just a `WHERE nummer between 1 and 9`

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason the use a `WHILE` at all here, you can achieve the above in a single statement:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS aantal,
       G.gebouw AS gebouw,
       --G.nummer, --You don't expose this in your attempt, but I suspect you should be.
       CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS [per datum]
FROM [VGNSalto].[dbo].[tb_Locks] L --Aliases are really useful
     --Don't forget to always schema qualify your objects.
     JOIN dbo.lt_Gebouw G ON L.name LIKE G.gebouw + '%' --G.gebouw = LEFT(L.name, 3) --Made SARGable
WHERE G.nummer >= 1
  AND G.nummer < 10
GROUP BY G.gebouw,
         G.nummer;
```

Note I add a few comments about your existing code as well, with some tips/improvements.